# MS-SQL Server cannot connect to Visual C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

i'm using Windows 10, Visual Studio 2019 and Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18.
My SQL Server working fine in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18 and i can connect to server with user that i created, but in Visual Studio when i try connect to the SQL Server, i have error.
this is the error: [image: image of error]
and this is my C# code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace dblab3
{
    public partial class AuthenticationForm : Form
    {
        public AuthenticationForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Return_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void Enter_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
            string connection_str = "server = " + servername_tBox + "; database = dblab03; user id = " + username_tBox + "; password = " + password_tBox;
            connection.ConnectionString = connection_str;
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                connection.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                return;
            }
            menuForm menu_frm = new menuForm();
            menu_frm.Show();
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the "mysql" tag?

Comment: You are using MySQL connection properties against Microsoft SQL Server. Use `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` to  help you get it right.

Comment: Also, if your *_tbox variables are TextBoxes, then you need to use *_tbox.Text to get their contents.